# Twitter API Post Request -- Error Code 215 Bad Authentication data

Tags: python, twitter, python-requests, micropython

I am building a Twitter bot in MicroPython to run on a NodeMCU ESP8266 board. MicroPython doesn't have support for OAuth 1.0 requests out of the box, so I had to roll my own.
I've been following these write-ups to build my program:

1. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/authorizing-a-request
2. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature

When ever I send a POST request to [send a tweet](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update), I get the following error response: `{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}`.

I wrote a small wrapper class for the MicroPython `urequests` module, called `oauth_requests`

```py
import urequests as requests

class oauth_request:
    @classmethod
    def post(cls, url, params, key_ring):
        """ Post method with OAuth 1.0
            Args:
                url (str): URL to send request to.
                params (dict): Params to append to URL.
                key_ring (dict): Dictionary with API keys.
            Returns:
                Response from POST request.
        """
        auth_header = cls.__create_auth_header("POST", url, params, **key_ring)
        headers = {"Authorization": auth_header}
        url += "?{}".format(
            "&".join([
                "{}={}".format(cls.__percent_encode(str(k)), cls.__percent_encode(str(v)))
                for k, v in params.items()
            ]))
        return requests.post(url, headers=headers)
```

The return value of `cls.__create_auth_header(...)` is an "OAuth" string, like the one at the end of link #1 above. I have validated that my implementation of the `HMAC-SHA1` algorithm produces the same output from the sample data in link #2 up above. I was able to send the same response through PostMan, so my API keys are valid.

Am I incorrectly creating the request headers correctly?

I have committed my code to [this](https://github.com/misimpso/esp8266_twitterbot) repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the fix for my problem. The main problem was I wasn't percent encoding my value for `oauth_signature`. However, even after that I was getting a new error, `{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}`.

From the link I originally posted up above about [creating the signature](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature), you build the base parameter string from percent-encoding, and "&" joining an `oauth` dictionary like this:

```py
url_params = {
    "status": "Tweeting from the future."
}

oauth = {
    "include_entities": "true",
    "oauth_consumer_key": consumer_key,
    "oauth_nonce": generate_nonce(),
    "oauth_signature_method": "HMAC-SHA1",
    "oauth_timestamp": 946684800 + time.time(),
    "oauth_token": access_token,
    "oauth_version": 1.0,
}

oauth.update(url_params)

base_string = percent_encode_and_join(oauth)
```

(The time value is odd because the micropython system time epoch starts in Jan 1st, 2000 instead of Jan 1st, 1970)

However when I was debugging the request using PostMan it was working. I realized that Postman couldn't know to add that `include_entities` entry when it is calculating the signature. Lo and behold when I removed that key from this dictionary, the error went away.

Refer to my repo up above for the code.